# Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' in Python

Tags: python, attributeerror, mysql-connector

I have this code

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']=''
app.config['MYSQL_DB']='appdb'
mysql = MySQL(appdb)
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='Apple'")
apple= cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
```

However, I get this error

> Attribute Error: Nonetype object has no attribute 'cursor'

How to solve this error?

Comment: sql connection wouldn't have successful. Thats why you are getting null for mysql.connection

Comment: I tried making it from another file with insert query instead of select and it works fine.Does that mean there's a connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import close_all_sessions
import mysql.connector
import time

username = 'MYSQL_USER'
password = 'MYSQL_PASSWORD!'
host = 'MYSQL_HOST'
port = 'MYSQL_port'
DB_NAME = 'MYSQL_DBname'

engine = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}")

n = 250
for i in range(0,vac.shape[0],n):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute("USE MYSQL_DBname")
        result = conn.execute(""SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='Apple'"")
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are in "app" not "appdb" which is why "mysql" is None, in other words no connection was made. Change it to MySQL(app).

It's better to check if the connection was made before executing a query.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']=''
app.config['MYSQL_DB']='appdb'
mysql = MySQL(app)
if mysql:
   print("Connection Successful!")
   cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='Apple'")
   apple= cursor.fetchone()
   cursor.close()
else:
   print("Connection Failed!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: appdb is the database name. app is the name of the flask application i'm trying to create

Comment: edited the response should be more clear now. What i meant was, you are not sending correct data in MySQL, just specifying your dbname is not enough.